# Running sha1sum into several directories

Tags: shell, find, checksum

I have several directories that share a common parent directory. In each directory there are regular files, but no other subdirectories. Something like this:

```
top/dir-1
top/dir-1/file-11
top/dir-1/file-12
top/dir-2
top/dir-2/file-21
top/dir-2/file-22
top/dir-3
top/dir-3/file-31
top/dir-3/file-32
```

I'd like to run `sha1sum` on those files and obtain the following checksum files:

```
top/dir-1/sha1sum
top/dir-2/sha1sum
top/dir-3/sha1sum
```

`top/dir-1/sha1sum`, for example, should contain only the checksums for `file-11` and `file-12`:

```
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx file-11
yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy file-12
```

I have tried several commands involving `find`, `sha1sum`, `cd`, a `for` loop and subshells, but without much success.

Last thing: both directories and files can have spaces in their names, so any solution should consider this.

Any ideas?

---

Edit. I finally tried with:

```
cd top
for i in *; do cd "${i}"; (sha1sum * > sha1sum); cd ..; done
```

It seems to work, but I'm still not sure if it's the right way for doing this kind of job.

Comment: @Mat: I've updated the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Better as:

```
cd top &&
for i in */; do (cd -- "$i" && sha1sum -- * > sha1sum); done
```